# 'ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that when I try to execute I get the error that Year is an invalid identifier, I don't understand why, is there an alternative to what I do that is not with year? Or is it no longer supported?

```
        SELECT 
            P.EVT_PRGM_EDITION,
            SUM(P.EVT_NBSESSIONS) AS SESSIONS
        FROM 
            PLANNING P, FACULTY F, PROGRAM PGR
        WHERE F.FAC_NUM=P.EVT_FAC1
        AND PGR.PRGM_NUM=P.EVT_PRGM
        AND P.EVT_STAT='ST001'
        AND (PGR.PRGM_CMAJ IS NULL OR PGR.PRGM_CMAJ <> 'S')
        AND CASE  WHEN MONTH(P.EVT_DATE) < 09 
            THEN  YEAR(P.EVT_DATE)-1 || '-' || YEAR(P.EVT_DATE) 
            ELSE  YEAR(P.EVT_DATE) || '-' || YEAR(P.EVT_DATE)+1 
            END = :ACAD_YEAR
        AND F.FAC_NUM = :PROFESSOR_ID
        GROUP BY P.EVT_PRGM_EDITION_IESE
```

Comment: Do `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P.EVT_DATE)`, the ANSI SQL way!

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for the info, I understand that you mean the "join" when I do the "from", right? Another thing, I have tried what you have told me with the date and it works, but now it gives me another error 'ORA-00932: inconsistent data types: expected DATE has been obtained NUMBER

Comment: It's quite easy to understand if you refer to [Datetime functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C) paragraph in the documentation. It's the most reliable source of what *should* work in some specific release of DBMS.

Comment: SQL is not universal. Each database vendor has its own dialect with its own functions and, often, its own syntax. You probably got function `YEAR()` in a codebase or document that referred to Microsoft SQL Server. You need to ensure your source material explicitly applies to Oracle.